# XAML Style Ribbon Bar

Tags: wpf, xaml, ribbon

I am new to Ribbons, can you please tell me how i style the Ribbon Bar in Visual Studio?
Got some probs here. Which is the right selector for the bar? I tried this one

```
Style TargetType="custom:Ribbon"
```

and

```
Style TargetType="ribbon:RibbonTab"
```

I also tried to extract the Ribbon Style from Blend. But i cant include it to my VS project because 
`custom:Ribbon` is seems to be wrong.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You should have Xml namespace decleration like so:

```xml
xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
```

with styles such as..

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:Ribbon}">
```

or

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonTab}">
```

A good start is the samples available alongside the library itself: [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11877)